# Proving if $f$ is strictly increasing and onto, there exists a strictly increasing and onto function $g$ such that $f(x)<g(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f : (a,b) → (c,d)$ is a strictly increasing onto function. Prove that there exists a $g: (a,b) → (c,d)$, which is also strictly increasing and onto, and $g(x) < f(x)$ for all $x ∈ (a,b)$.

I have tried defining $g$ as $g(x) = f(x) - k$ for some small $k$, but that does not seem like the right answer.

Comment: I think you are proceeding in the right direction. Differentiate $g$ and you can prove that $g$ is strictly increasing function , and onto.

Comment: @AkashRoy why should $f$ be necessarily differentiable?

Comment: @Anurag it is given that $f$ is strictly inreasing function so it has to be necessarily differentiable.

Comment: @AkashRoy: even if $f$ is assumed to differentiable, your approach goes wrong: e.g.,  if $a = c$ and $b= d$ and  $f$ is the identity function?

Comment: Differentiation is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Did not get you @Rob Arthan

Comment: Oh now I got it . What if it becomes an identity function e.g $f(x)=x$

Comment: @AkashRoy: The identity function on $(a, b)$ is a strictly increasing constant function and its derivative is neither strictly increasing nor onto. (Apologies, I omitted "its derivative" before this edit.)

Comment: But in the question it is specified that $f$is strictly increasing.

Comment: @AkashRoy: see my edited comment.

Comment: Yeah now its okay

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use $g(x) = f(x)-k$ because that won't have image $(c,d)$ if $k \ne 0$ (because $f(x)$ *does* have image $(c,d)$).

But you can do something similar. First change coordinates on $(c,d)$, using the coordinate change function
$$h : (c,d) \to \mathbb R
$$
given by
$$h(x) = \tan\left(\pi\left(\frac{x-c}{d-c}\right)-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
$$
This function $h : (c,d) \to \mathbb R$ is strictly increasing and onto, hence its inverse $h^{-1} : \mathbb R \to (c,d)$ is also strictly increasing and onto.

Now define
$$g(x) = h^{-1}\bigl(h(f(x))-k)\bigr)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: this is easy if $a = c = -\infty$ and $b = d = +\infty$. You can transform the problem for finite $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ into the easy case using the functions $\tan$ and $\arctan$.